# TYPO3 - writing out subpages of a page under certain uid

Tags: typo3, typoscript

So I have something that kinda looks like this:

---

```
## Menu [Begin]


lib.menuindoor = HMENU
lib.menuindoor.entryLevel = 0
lib.menuindoor.wrap =        <li class="menu-item">|</li>     
lib.menuindoor.1 = TMENU
lib.menuindoor.1.NO {   
  allWrap = |
}

lib.menuindoor = HMENU
lib.menuindoor.entryLevel = 1
lib.menuindoor.wrap = <ul>|</ul>
lib.menuindoor.1 = TMENU
lib.menuindoor.1.NO {
  allWrap = <li>|</li>
}
## Menu [End]
```

The thing I would like to do now is making it so that only subpages of a certain Page get written out,

Say I have

```
Indoor(with id=63)
      subpage
      subpage
      subpage

Outdor (with id=67)
       subpage
       subpage
       subpage
```

So here I Would like to only write out pages that are a subpage of page with id=63.

I tried using this, but it didn't work:

```
lib.menuindoor.special = directory
lib.menuindoor.special.value = 63
```

Any tips how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.special = directory` is proper way to do that what you want to achieve. Anyway while using any `special` menu, you should not define a `entryLevel` as it probably takes a priority over your settings (check [special menu properties](http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/HMENU))